# About the word "hernach"

Tags: vocabulary, archaism

Immanuel Kant uses *hernach* quite a lot in his writings.

However, [here](http://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/hernach) the word is said to be used only regionally; but I doubt that Kant would have used such words in his works.

Is it perhaps an archaism as considered from our perspective?

Comment: Could you add two or three examples of Kant's use of *hernach*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, today, *hernach* actually is an anachronism. Everyone would nowadays say "danach".

If you consider the time Kant wrote his work, the word *hernach* would have been much more common than it is today. A quick look in [Grimms Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GH06810#XGH06810) (1835) shows that *da[r]nach* is explained with *hernach*, but not vice versa (so *hernach* can be considered more common than *danach*), and a [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=danach%2Chernach&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdanach%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chernach%3B%2Cc0) search shows that *hernach* was more common than *danach* until about 1840.

Today, the word is only used in a number of dialects.

Answer (score 4):

> ... but I doubt that Kant would have used such words in his works.

In German language a lot of dialects exist which differ a lot. I've heard that some dialects even satisfy the criteria of being "languages".

According to the [Wikipedia article about "Standarddeutsch"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standarddeutsch) in the time when Kant, Goethe or Schiller lived a unified German language spoken all over Germany did not exist, yet.

As a consequence their works could not be written in "German language" but they had to write in one of multiple German dialects.

Ps.: Even today people typically do not speak the unified German language but the local variant of German (having own words and even an own grammar).

Comment: I want to add: Today (in 2017) there still is no unified German language spoken all over the German sprachraum (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprachraum ). Switch through TV stations from Germany (»Abitur«), Austria (»Sackerl«) and Switzerland (»parkieren«), and you will hear words in each country, that are used only there (and regions in the close neighborhood, the borders are not sharp)

Comment: There are several words which were used regularly in German in the 19th century but which today can be found almost exclusively in some dialects. Other examples: geschwind (quickly), garstig (nasty).

Comment: The case with "danach" and "hernach" is not so much a matter of space, but rather one of time.